# How to SSH tunnel from jump server to another server without directly logging in to the jump server

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ssh, ssh-tunnel, localtunnel

I know, this question has been asked a lot, but still I have problems using `ssh` proxy.

I have an `EC2` server (running a simple web server) which is in a private network in `aws`. And have a `jumphost` to connect to it. `jumphost` is in a public network. Only way I can login in to the web server instance is through the `jumphost`.

So I have created `~/.ssh/config` file in my local computer as below:

```
Host jumphost
  Hostname <Retracted-Public-IP>
  user ec2-user
  IdentityFile /Users/jananath/.ssh/private-key.pem
```

I can log in to the `jumphost` as: `ssh jumphost` and it works.

And in the `jumphost` above I have configured `~/.ssh/config` as below:

```
Host my-web-server
  Hostname <Retracted-Private-IP>
  user ec2-user
  IdentityFile ~/.ssh/web-server-private-key.pem
```

And I can ssh into the web server (from `jumphost`) as `ssh my-web-server` and it works.

I don't want to log in to the `jumphost` everytime I need to log into the web server, so I tried proxying.

Therefore, I added another block to my local `~/.ssh/config` file as below:

```
Host jumphost
  Hostname <Retracted-Public-IP>
  user ec2-user
  IdentityFile /Users/jananath/.ssh/private-key.pem

Host my-web-server
   ProxyCommand ssh jumphost -W %h:%p
```

And I tried: `ssh my-web-server` and it gives the below output:

> kex_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
> Connection closed by UNKNOWN port 65535

Can someone help me fix this?

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
Host my-web-server
   ProxyCommand ssh jumphost nc %h %p
```

You can also try :

```
ssh -oProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p jumphost" my-web-server
```

Third command worth to try :

```
ssh -J jumphost my-web-server
```

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: I have no idea why this is not working. But it doesn't work even after trying as per your answer

Comment: Both solutions work on my system. Did you get same error when trying the second solution ? Maybe you can upload the trace of this command : `ssh -vvv my-web-server`

Answer (score 0):

Copy the public key of your local machine to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` of the remote machine and not just the jump server. This will enable passwordless login from the local machine using `ssh -J`. If your ip is ipv6 make the following modification in the config file of your local machine.

```
Host jumphost
  Hostname Retracted-Public-IPv6
  user ec2-user
  IdentityFile /Users/jananath/.ssh/private-key.pem

Host my-web-server
   ProxyCommand ssh jumphost -W %[h]:%p
```

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution because of the jumphost can't find the `.pem` file. So that we need point the `.pem` files `path.sample`

`ssh -J jumphost ec2-user@172.31.12.10 -i "/Users/aaa/key.pem"`